# Vim for doing java and C#?

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, vim

I hope you let me off on the following technicality. I know this question has been asked before on here, but I want the most spanking new *up to date answer* and one that is tailored to my specific background and situation.

I asked my friends around about using vim for java and C# and they told me that vim ports suck and I should give up. I read about the plugin's that people use for Eclipse and Visual Studio and they told me those suck bad and aren't vim. Are they right?

I just learned vim this summer and I don't want to go back. I use Eclipse and Visual studio and I wonder if there are really good tools I could obtain that would allow me to code in native vim style for Eclipse/MS Visual Studio without losing the advantage of those debuggers. You know, basically allowing me to code in Java and C#.

I read on here about VIM plugin for Eclipse. However, I heard that is like only the hjkl commands. None of the cool stuff like scripting. So basically, to repeat myself for emphasis, do any of you know of really cool vim tools/plugins/whatever I can use for Eclipse and Visual Studio that will allow me to code in vim and get the best of both worlds?

Comment: There are VIM bindings to Visual Studio

Comment: If you want, try out Sublime Text 2 with its vim bindings. It's a pretty amazing editor, and if you don't need stuff like intellisense it works very well.

Comment: @jli But intellisense is what *makes* VisualStudio, IMO.

Comment: Not using Intellisense is like coding with one hand tied behind your back. You *can* do it, but why make life harder for no reason?

Comment: What is the question here? Is it _should I use Vim_? Or is it _what non-Vim editor should I use that supports Vim keybindings_? Also: _[my friends] told me that vim ports suck and I should give up._ -- **which** ports? Ports for windows, OSX and naturally UN*X are all perfectly usable.

Comment: @pb2q I want to use Vim on Eclipse and Visual Studio and/or at least with java and C#. You do bring up a good point on with what ports. I use Mac OSX, Ubuntu, and W7. I was told to stay away from vim on W7, BUT obviously I am going to need something to work with MS Visual Studio.

Comment: Vim and gVim work just fine on Win7. Some tips [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio) about integration w/ VisStudio. Just get used to having an editor separate from the IDE and the workflow is great.

Comment: @pb2q Thanks! I am excited. I really want to use vim to increase my productivity. Appreciate the links my friend. Thanks to all for answering my very specific questions. But considering the crap advice I was getting in person. This was the ONLY place I thought I could ask. Thanks and hugs to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) for Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio for over 3 years now and I highly recommend it.

It is not 100 percent of Vim, but goes far, far beyond "hjkl commands," with all the named buffers, navigation and support for really powerful things like macro recording and playback. It uses a config file (viemurc) just like Vim to allow you to customize your mappings.

You can map ViEmu commands to Visual Studio commands and macros to combine and extend the power. It really is the "best of both worlds," as you say -- Visual Studio offers too much to use any other editor for C# development.

ViEmu is a commercial product -- it does cost money -- but for the productivity and Vimmy joy I get from using it, I can say it has been a terrific investment.